# Make Gist from Github repo for display on bl.ocks.org

Tags: d3.js, github-pages, gist

I have created a data visualization app and posted it as a [Github page](https://github.com/tedstrauss/expenditures).
I would now like to display this on the [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/) site that aggregates D3.js visualizations.
How can I start from the github repo and create a gist that maintains the relative dependencies of the repo code? Will I need to refactor all the code to make a single-file app that points to only CDN sources?

Comment: bl.ocks.org doesn't aggregate visualisations, it's simply a viewer for gists. Have a look at some of the blocks/gists that are out there (there are plenty!) and you will see what's required. Basically, the gist needs to be self-contained.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's easiest to learn by example.  Take the example on the bl.ocks home page:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1353700

Now to see the gist that generated it, just take the id number from the end of the url and appent it the gist url, like so:

http://gist.github.com/1353700

That gist contains 3 files, but two are optional.  The only requirement for a block to display is to have index.html.  That file should contain your a full html file with your js script any includes to cdn resources like d3.  Optionally, you could put your javascript code in a separate file and add that to the gist, and then link to it from your index.html file.

You can also add a README.md and thumbnail.png, if you'd like to provide a description of your example and an image for it.  This is explained on the bl.ocks home page as well.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

Once you have the example on GIST, all you have to do is copy the extension (ie, "username/hash") and put it after bl.ocks.org/.  So if you this gist:

```
https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4063423
```

It can be viewed via bl.ocks at the following URL:

```
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423
```

It's so good that you don't need to do any extra work after creating the gist.

Comment: Thank you!  This was the crucial step.