# How to implement D3 hierarchy view

Tags: html, json, d3.js

I am trying to make a hierarchy table, in which I want to show tree-structure with help of D3js.org, but it is not showing. Can anyone of you help me in solving my problem.

I am using code : index.html and readme.json from  https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1062288 link.

But by using these two files and same code as given in link, I am unable to see the hierarchy. https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1062288.

```js
// readme.json



{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "animate",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
    {
     "name": "interpolate",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
      {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
      {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
      {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
      {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
      {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "data",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "converters",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
      {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
      {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
      {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
      {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
    {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
    {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
    {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
    {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
    {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "display",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
    {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
    {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
    {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "flex",
   "children": [
    {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "physics",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
    {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
    {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
    {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
    {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
    {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
    {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
    {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "query",
   "children": [
    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
    {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
    {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
    {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
    {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
    {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
    {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
    {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
    {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
    {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
    {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
    {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
    {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
    {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
    {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
    {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
    {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
    {
     "name": "methods",
     "children": [
      {"name": "add", "size": 593},
      {"name": "and", "size": 330},
      {"name": "average", "size": 287},
      {"name": "count", "size": 277},
      {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
      {"name": "div", "size": 595},
      {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
      {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
      {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
      {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
      {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
      {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
      {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
      {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
      {"name": "max", "size": 283},
      {"name": "min", "size": 283},
      {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
      {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
      {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
      {"name": "not", "size": 386},
      {"name": "or", "size": 323},
      {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
      {"name": "range", "size": 772},
      {"name": "select", "size": 296},
      {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
      {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
      {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
      {"name": "update", "size": 307},
      {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
      {"name": "where", "size": 299},
      {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
      {"name": "_", "size": 264}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
    {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
    {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
    {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
    {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
    {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
    {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
    {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
    {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
    {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "scale",
   "children": [
    {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
    {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
    {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
    {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
    {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
    {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
    {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
    {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
    {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
    {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "util",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
    {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
    {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
    {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
    {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
    {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
    {
     "name": "heap",
     "children": [
      {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
      {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
    {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
    {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
    {
     "name": "math",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
      {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
      {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
    {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
    {
     "name": "palette",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
      {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
      {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
      {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
    {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
    {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
    {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
    {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "vis",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "axis",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
      {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
      {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
      {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
      {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "controls",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
      {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
      {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
      {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
      {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
      {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
      {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
      {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
      {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
      {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
      {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "data",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
      {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
      {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
      {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
      {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
      {
       "name": "render",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
      {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
      {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "events",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "legend",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
      {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
      {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "operator",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "distortion",
       "children": [
        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "encoder",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "filter",
       "children": [
        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
      {
       "name": "label",
       "children": [
        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "layout",
       "children": [
        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
      {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
      {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
      {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
      {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Force-Directed Graph</title>
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json("readme.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  update();
});

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update the links…
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Exit any old links.
  link.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new links.
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  // Update the nodes…
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; }).style("fill", color);

  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new nodes.
  node.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

// Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    update();
  }
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}

</script>
```

Comment: edited ..... now can you help me in getting desired output.

Comment: Are there any errors displayed in your js console?
are you using the files locally on your computer?

Comment: How are you trying to run this? If you have a git account you can fork the gist then [redirect it to bl.ocks.org](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20821883/2670182) to run it.  You can of course push your own modified code and data to your gist and see that update in bl.ocks.org also.  Otherwise you need to set up a server stack on your pc an run from localhost as mentioned by @jhinzmann.

Comment: yes i am using files locally in computer, nothing is visible when i run it in chrome. I want to use this tree structure: when it runs successfully , in GGTS using Grails to run from localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using the files locally on your computer and browsing them with chrome.
`d3.json(...)` loads data via XMLHttpRequest. In your [JavaScript console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) (where you should always look first if you have problems with JavaScript) you should get an error message like `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///...../data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Loading local files via ajax is not possible with chrome. Other browsers may allow to do so. Just checked safari and firefox and both do the job.

If you want to stick with your browser, you should look for a *local webserver* for your system.

Comment: yes you are right, i am using files locally on my computer and browsing them using chrome. But i am not getting anything in chrome when i run index.html file, not even any error.

Comment: You have  to open your JS console. See [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) for an explanation. JS errors are displayed there and not on the page.

Comment: Great that i could help you. Since your Problem is solved, please  mark my answer as accepted